# Incorrect dollar sign is appeared in android

Tags: java, android

i am programmatically adding $ sign to a textview text, but it is shown incorrectly, as you can see in screenshots attached. I want it like normal dollar sign of keyboard and not this dollar sign of android keyboard.

Screenshot:

[image: what the dollar sign looks like]

Comment: You have not attached screenshots, please attach the screenshots.

Comment: @DhirajSharma no, they are not available there

Comment: no, it redirects to GlobalLogic SSO

Comment: No. Not for me. There's an image button in the top bar of the editor field when you create/edit your question. Insert your images there please.

Comment: Hmm, try to check your encoding. This is the first what somes to mind. Try to use UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: actually it requires higher reputaion

Comment: That's a normal dollar sign. Nothing special about it.

Comment: i have added new url of dropbox, screenshot is in that

Comment: @RogerGustavsson no this dollar sign is different from the dollar sign we have in keyboard. i want this $ dollar sign

Comment: You're setting a different font, that'll change what the dollar sign looks like too

Comment: read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239345/dollar-sign-used-as-currency-renders-incorrectly-in-android-app

Comment: @DhirajSharma If you view this page from your android device, with the same browser you used when producing the screenshot, the dollar sign in your comment above should look like your screenshot. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is a typeface "issue", as @JoeFrostick pointed out in a comment.

Different typefaces (fonts) render the same character differently. That's actually the whole point with typefaces.

If you want to experiment with different typefaces online, you can go to [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts). The following screenshot shows the fonts selected by default when I went there. I entered a dollar-sign in the Preview Text input box. The screenshot shows two different renditions of the dollar-sign by the first two fonts, Open Sans and Roboto.

[image: Showing different rendition of the dollar-sign]